# Here map crash when launch here map application from other applicion

Tags: maps, here-api

When I am going to launch Here map through adb command application got crashed.
I am launching **com.here.app.maps/com.here.app.MainActivity** and got following exception.

> 08-03 09:54:08.416 F/b       ( 6575): Caused by: com.here.android.mpa.common.UnintializedMapEngineException: Cannot created HERE SDK objects before MapEngine is initialized.  See MapEngine.init()
>   08-03 09:54:08.416 F/b       ( 6575):   at com.nokia.maps.MapLoaderImpl.(SourceFile:145)
>   08-03 09:54:08.416 F/b       ( 6575):   at com.nokia.maps.MapLoaderImpl.a(SourceFile:131)
>   08-03 09:54:08.416 F/b       ( 6575):   at com.here.android.mpa.odml.MapLoader.(SourceFile:562)
>   08-03 09:54:08.416 F/b       ( 6575):   at com.here.android.mpa.odml.MapLoader.getInstance(SourceFile:294)
>   08-03 09:54:08.416 F/b       ( 6575):   at com.here.components.packageloader.aa.(SourceFile:13)
>   08-03 09:54:08.416 F/b       ( 6575):   at com.here.components.packageloader.k.(SourceFile:12)
>   08-03 09:54:08.416 F/b       ( 6575):   at com.here.components.packageloader.k.(SourceFile:10)
>   08-03 09:54:08.416 F/b       ( 6575):   ... 11 more

Answer (score 0):

You tried to new a class from com.here.android.mpa.* as a static or class variable?

Before the engine is initialized, objects cannot be properly loaded.

Please check your code for any class instance objects.

EG:

```
class MyClass {
    private GeoCoordiante gc = new GeoCoordinate() // BAD

}
```